# How to gain more control over onNodeDrop event in the PrimeNG tree component?

Tags: angular, tree, drag-and-drop, primeng

I've decided to use PrimeNG components for our company's project, specifically the tree component. It worked nicely until I've started implementing drag & drop functionality. My main problem is when using the drag & drop on the tree when it's filtered, the changes are not being reflected in the original unfiltered tree model. I suppose when filtering the tree another temporary model is created and when the filter is disabled, the original unfiltered model is displayed and the filtered one is tossed away.
I tried to implement my own logic which would allow me to drag & drop nodes even when the tree is filtered but I cannot do it as the *onNodeDrop* event doesn't tell me if the dragged node is being inserted before/on/after target node. Is there a way to get the information?
I've checked the source code and this is all the information provided by the event:

```
let dropParams = { ...this.createDropPointEventMetadata(<number>position) };
this.tree.onNodeDrop.emit({
    originalEvent: event,
    dragNode: dragNode,
    dropNode: this.node,
    index: this.index,
    accept: () => {
        this.processPointDrop(dropParams);
    }
});
```

Am I missing something?